# can I run the hello.js example for spookyjs on nitrous.io?

Tags: nitrousio, spookyjs

Here are the exact steps I took to try to run the hello.js example for spooky js on nitrous.

**1.** I installed phantomjs, nodejs(already installed), and casperjs.
`$ npm install -g casperjs`

Casper warns me that While CasperJS is installable via npm, it’s not a NodeJS package, neither it’s capable to require native NodeJS modules.

Because of this I wanted to use spookyjs which is a nodejs package.
Then, I installed phantom js: `$ npm install phantomjs`
Finally, I installed spookyjs: `$ npm install spooky`

**2.** I tried running the hello.js example using
`$ node node_modules/spooky/examples/hello.js`

**3.** I end up getting this error:
`{ [Error: Child terminated with non-zero exit code 1] details: { code: 1, signal: null }`}

Am I doing something wrong or can casperjs not be installed?

[this is where I found spookyjs](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS)

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the phantomjs and casperjs runtime?  The npm packages for phantomjs and casperjs call out to these runtimes.  The error you see is when it can not find the casperjs runtime.

I'm not very familiar with nitrous.io and how much freedom you have to install other runtimes.  Here's what I used for installing them on Linux:  https://www.dvdheiden.nl/2013/07/30/installing-phantomjs-and-casperjs-on-linux/